# How to get HWID in C++

Tags: c++, uuid, drm, hwid

I'm making a program, to stop pirating i'm adding a hwid lock. I want to use the output of the wmic command `wmic csproduct get uuid`. However I am not sure how to set its output as a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
HW_PROFILE_INFO hwProfileInfo;
if (GetCurrentHwProfile(&hwProfileInfo))
    printf("HWID: %s\n", hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid);
```

There is no guarantee this value won't change though. This is the GUID of current hardware profile on Windows, but it can be set up to have more than one of those.

I believe this GUID will change automatically if there's a drastic hardware change, like replacing the motherboard. Though this would also deactivate the Windows license, so I suppose Windows too rely on hardware profile to validate it's licensing.

Comment: It is not the same data